# Is it circular reasoning to compute the ELBO using MCMC?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood, kullback-leibler, marginal-distribution, bic

Let's say we have a posterior distribution $q(\theta) = p(\theta \mid D, \mathcal{M})$ over parameters $\theta$ given data $D$ and a model $\mathcal{M}$. As is often the case, computing $q$ is hard, because of its normalization constant (aka *partition function*, or *model evidence*) in the denominator of $q$
$$
Z = p(D \mid \mathcal{M}) = \int{ p(D, \theta \mid \mathcal{M}) d\theta}
$$
where one needs to integrate over potentially huge parameter spaces. However, we can rewrite $\ln{Z}$ using the *Helmholtz free energy* (like done [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11571-021-09696-9)):
$$
\ln{Z} = -F_H = \underbrace{\int{ q(\theta) \ln{p(D \mid \theta, \mathcal{M}) d\theta}}}_{\text{ELBO for accuracy}} - \underbrace{\int{ q(\theta) \ln{\frac{q(\theta)}{p(\theta \mid \mathcal{M})}} d\theta}}_{\text{KL-divergence for complexity}}
$$
Now, using MCMC allows me to draw samples $\hat{\theta} \sim q$ from the posterior while only being able to actually compute the joint $p(D, \theta \mid \mathcal{M})$. I get that I cannot compute the model evidence using MCMC, because of the KL-divergence, which would require me to be able to compute $q$. But I should be able to compute the other term (which is often called *ELBO*, I think) without problems using a Monte Carlo estimator:
$$
\text{ELBO} \approx \frac{1}{S} \sum_{i=1}^S{\ln{p(D \mid \hat{\theta}_i, \mathcal{M})}}
$$
where the $\hat{\theta}_i \sim q(\theta)$ are $S$ samples drawn e.g. using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

On one hand, I'm afraid this is circular reasoning, because we used just that (log-)likelihood to draw the samples in the first place. On the other hand, in the BIC we also get an parameter value $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$ from maximizing the function we try to estimate. So is this something one can do? And if yes, would it make sense to improve the BIC by using the MCMC estimator for the ELBO instead of the maximum log-likelihood?

Comment: There are plenty of MC(MC) methods to approximate the evidence. See eg Gelman & Meng (1998), [Chen, Shao & Ibrahim (1999).](https://amzn.to/3P3Lwf9), [some slides of mine](https://www.slideshare.net/xianblog/can-we-estimate-a-constant), and [further slides](https://www.slideshare.net/xianblog/course-on-bayesian-computational-methods).

Comment: See also this X validated question: https://www.slideshare.net/xianblog/course-on-bayesian-computational-methods

Comment: And [Friel & Wyse (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1957).

Comment: Thanks for those references! Especially the last one seems like a really comprehensive overview!
But my question was not about methods to compute the evidence. I am well aware of quite a number of them. My question was about a part of the evidence and if I can compute it easily. Do you have any take on that?